# folder observer in jboss

Tags: jboss, directory, message-queue

I need to write a folder observer that will run in JBoss. The idea is that as soon as a file will appear in a folder we should handle the file and move it somewhere. 
I wrote a simple Java class that will use the Java 7 NIO and it observe the folder. Once a file exists appears in the folder I move it to another folder and process it. Currently what I have done is as soon as the file appears I move it and create a new thread to process it. 
Since this suppose to run in JBoss I understand now that creating threads in JBoss is not the way to do that and I should use message queues.
Therefore I am about to change the class and call the queue and pass it an object of the file location and expect the JBoss to handle it. 
My question is basically am I doing it right? is this the right way to do that in JBoss? Any process that I want to be done in a multi tasking way should be done with message queues?

Thanks in advance,

Sharon

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create un-managed threads in a container. JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6 has the facility to let you define your own thread pools and permit the application container to manage these threads. If you want to use threads to do this, you should use a container managed thread pool. Otherwise, a message passing based implementation would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure why this application needs to run in a container/JBoss. Setting that aside, one option is to utilize the message oriented model using JMS queues/topics instead of dealing with files.

The other option is to create a [JEE6 timer service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) that will execute your code to move files at a certain interval. So in this scenario JBoss will manage your threads using the ejb thread pool.